# Selenium IDE - timing of chooseOkOnNextConfirmation during page forward

Tags: javascript, popup, selenium-ide

I'm trying to book a table at a restaurant. After I click on the book button, the page forwards, checks back to confirm availability with the server (over the course of maybe 2 seconds) and then opens a JavaScript confirmation pop-up in the browser.

Will I be fine with `chooseOkOnNextConfirmation` before I press the button and thus before the page forwards or should I add another (or move) `chooseOkOnNextConfirmation` after the click during the availability check?

Would it hurt to have several `chooseOkOnNextConfirmation` commands in a row? Would they interfere with each other?

It is essential that I get the timing right. Too early and the command might be executed on the wrong page, too late and the JavaScript pop-up stops my script. Please note that I can not test the script nor can I look at the page's JavaScript properties as bookings are closed right now and will only be available later.

Alternatively, should I use `clickAndWait` instead of `click` (the URL doesn't change though and the command may cause errors)? Can I use `assertConfirmationPresent` to determine whether the page is fully loaded before `assertConfirmation` or will it be too late since the pop-up already stopped my script?

What I have for now looks as follows:

```
chooseOkOnNextConfirmation
click                           //*[@id="table_id"]/thead/tr/th[1]/input
assertConfirmation              glob:Are you sure you want to submit your request 
                                for the following unit: Location Description:*
```

Btw, turns out globbing doesn't work for the command `assertConfirmation`. I get the error **Confirmation message doesn't match actual message** in the log unless the text in target matches the text in the pop-up exactly. Any ideas how to work around or how to make `glob:*` work?